# Recursive function put character in front of list only once

Tags: haskell, recursion

So I have to write a recursive function which replaces the given word list with letters using a former function. That part works perfectly. But I also have to put a `'|'` symbol in front of the list and the same symbol and a `'\n'` symbol after the list. I have this code right now:

```
showRow [] = []
showRow (x:xs) = '|' : showCell x : showRow xs ++ ['|'] ++ ['\n']
```

This puts the first symbol before every letter and the two other symbols after the list multiple times. How can I add these symbols to the start and end of the list only once within this function?

Comment: Can you use a helper function?

Comment: Why do you need to recurse? You want to show them only once, right? `showRow (x:xs) = '|' : showCell x : xs ++ "|\n"`? It's uncertain since we don't know the lists type. And if you need to use `showCell` on every element, use `"|" ++ map showCell xs ++ "|\n"`.

Comment: @Zeta Presumably because it’s homework.

Comment: Yes, it is homework, but it actually wasn't a requirement to make it recursive and I didn't know about map, so thank you for the idea, I could make it work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right solution for your problem (follow the recommended `map` method in the comments), but to show one way of handling recursive function with different first and last behavior

```
showRow [] = []
showRow x = go x True
    where go x True   = '|': go x False
          go [] _     = "\n"
          go (x:xs) _ = (showCell x) ++ ('|': go xs False)
```

a dummy boolean triggers the initial value handling and empty list triggers the final value handing.